# How to design a message Toast in sapui5

Tags: javascript, css, sapui5, message

I want to display a message toast in 2 lines, instead of 1,
How do I do that?
In addition I need to design it with less opacity , specific color and size?
Any idea?‏
var message = this._oBundle.getText("Paymentdeclined");
sap.m.MessageToast.show(message);

Comment: Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the tour to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]`snippet editor

Answer (score 0):

In order to display text in new line, you can include newline character(\n) where ever you need a line break. In order to change the opacity and color of MessageToast, you need to apply your custom CSS. Example :-

```
 sap.m.MessageToast.show('Lorem \n ipsum \n dolor sit amet', {
                        duration: 3000, 
                        width: "15rem", // default max width supported 
                    });

/* width properties are required only if the width required is more than 15rem*/
    .sapMMessageToast{
        background : #629192 !important;
        width:25rem !important;
        max-width : 25rem !important;
        opacity: 0.5 !important;
    }
```

But remember that this will be applied to all the MessageToast toasts.